#  How to inherit keyboard property?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, keyboard

Hi I have created my own keyboard and added my keyboard to the `inputview` of the `uitextview` it is working properly. Now I want to inherit all the property of `uitextview` like Auto-correct,word-capital etc etc.How can I inherit all that property.
I have tried like this

```
[uitextview conformsToProtocol:@protocol(UITextInputTraits)];
```

but this doesn't work. what can I try more to get all the property of `uitextview`

Comment: Check out `UITextInputTraits` protocol.

Comment: @Eimantas: I'm not sure that applies with a custom keyboard, where nik's is presumably manually and directly modifying the textfield's content after receiving `IBAction` messages. I beleive text input traits mediate between the standard keyboard(s) and the text field.

Comment: @jrturton I'm pointing nik's to mechanism that is used to modify the standard keyboard's appearance. Maybe he can use same methods to modify custom keyboard's appearance/behavior.

Comment: sorry I cant reply you soon. I have created a custom  view and add that custom view to the inputview of uitextview.